# svg manipulation app - record and play svg manipulations

Tags: d3.js, svg, snap.svg

I'm looking to build a moble app where the user can take an SVG image, manipulate it under a "recording", and then send the recording to a friend for them to "replay".

I have some experience with D3.js and have also looked at Snap.svg library for SVG manipulation but I'm not fully wrapping my head around how to implement this.

In particular, what's a good way to be able to save the manipulations the user is making and then "replay" them? For example, I can use D3.js to manipulate the SVG, but since this is code-based, I can't exactly "serialize" the animation in order to send to someone else and for them to be able to "replay" it. I don't want to go down the route of code generation..

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how complex your application targets are. However, it is easy to serialise updates in an SVG as JSON array and replay them using d3. Here is a small example for the same.

**Steps**:

1. Update SVG by using update buttons.
2. Revert the chart by clicking on clear button.
3. Now click play button to replay the last updates.

```js
var defaults = [{
  key: "r",
  val: 15,
  type: "attr"
}, {
  key: "fill",
  val: "blue",
  type: "style"
}];
var updates = [];
var c20 = d3.scale.category20();
var circles = d3.selectAll("circle");

d3.select("#increase_rad")
  .on("click", function() {
    var val = parseInt(d3.select("circle").attr("r")) + 1;
    circles.attr("r", val);
    updates.push({
      "key": "r",
      "val": val,
      "type": "attr"
    });
    enableButton();
  });

d3.select("#decrease_rad")
  .on("click", function() {
    var val = parseInt(d3.select("circle").attr("r")) - 1;
    circles.attr("r", val);
    updates.push({
      "key": "r",
      "val": val,
      "type": "attr"
    });
    enableButton();
  });

d3.select("#change_color")
  .on("click", function() {
    var val = c20(Math.floor(Math.random() * (18) + 1));
    circles.style("fill", val);
    updates.push({
      "key": "fill",
      "val": val,
      "type": "style"
    });
    enableButton();
  });

d3.select("#clear")
  .on("click", function() {
    applyEffects(defaults);
  });
d3.select("#play")
  .on("click", function() {
    applyEffects(updates);
  });

function applyEffects(effects, delay) {
  var trans = circles.transition()
  effects.forEach(function(update) {
    if (update.type == "attr") {
      trans = trans.attr(update.key, update.val).transition();
    } else {
      trans = trans.style(update.key, update.val).transition();
    }
  });
}

function enableButton() {
  d3.select("#clear").attr("disabled", null);
  d3.select("#play").attr("disabled", null);
}
```

```css
svg {
  background: white;
}
.link {
  stroke: black;
}
.node {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear" disabled />
  <input type="button" value="Play" id="play" disabled />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Increase Radius" id="increase_rad" />
  <input type="button" value="Decrease Radius" id="decrease_rad" />
  <input type="button" value="Change Color" id="change_color" />
</div>
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <g id="links">
    <line class="link" x1="138.0538594815113" y1="55.927846328346924" x2="58.77306466322782" y2="110.43892621419347"></line>
    <line class="link" x1="138.0538594815113" y1="55.927846328346924" x2="195.04044384802015" y2="133.44259356292176"></line>
  </g>
  <g id="nodes">
    <g class="node" transform="translate(138.0538594815113,55.927846328346924)">
      <circle r=15></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(58.77306466322782,110.43892621419347)">
      <circle r=15></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(195.04044384802015,133.44259356292176)">
      <circle r=15></circle>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much! Shame on the 3 people that tried to close this as an illegitimate question :)